# HTML radio and checkboxes not checking/unchecking internally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, radio-button

So visually they have the correct behavior. Only 1 radio button in a set is checked and the checkbox checks/unchecks in reaction to pressing it but it seems when checking the status of the inputs in the console that isn't the case. So I have:

```
<input id="addon-fixed" type="checkbox" value=True checked />

<input id="addon-type0" name="addon-type" type="radio" checked/>Addon<br>
<input id="addon-type1" name="addon-type" type="radio"/>Cutout
```

But regardless of what I click the behavior is always the same

```
$('#addon-fixed').attr('checked')   // always there

$('#addon-type0').attr('checked')   // always there 
$('#addon-type1').attr('checked')   // always undefined
```

Comment: Try with `.prop()` -- Also, when are you running these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr()`

```
$('#addon-fixed').prop('checked')
```

Checking or unchecking the checkbox changes the `checked` *property*, it doesn't change the element's *attribute*.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to check whether it is checked or not:
Use this...

```
if($('#addon-fixed').is(':checked')){
//checked
}else {
//unchekced
}
```

hope this will help you...